# SQL Server : calculate PnL between Repeating Values of Running Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please look at the columns: `K_ExeShares`, `ExePrice` and `RunningTotal`. 
My task is to calculate the `PnL for "1", "2"`(Shown in schema attached)

Edit: added link to the table scripted

[FULL SCRIPTED DATA IN T-SQL](https://pastebin.com/hrWNg67m)

[Trimmed Dataset to Two trades](https://pastebin.com/Wrr1hgUm)

[image]

So workflow is next:

1. Trader opens position shown as "a" (marked as 'OPENING' in the Direction column) in some security (SQ in this case) then closes it "marked as "b" ( 'CLOSING' in the Direction column).
2. After he closes that position Running total becomes 0
3. I need to calculate Profit & Lost on "1", "2" as "Money Paid to open that position" minus "Money received to close that position". And do it for every pair of OPENING/CLOSING
4. Please note PnL needs to be calculated BETWEEN TWO Zeroes in the RunningTotal column. In the attached example as between rows id 1 and 7, then between 8 and 21 etc.

**Between EACH ZERO the PnL NEEDS TO BE CALCULATED SEPARATELY**. In other words **each batch of Opening/Closing should be an atomic PnL calculation**. We cannot use the continious one as sometimes incorrect values and numbers can be introduced which will break all the future calculations down the road. So PnL in "1" should be totally separated from PnL calc in "2". Because there are hundreds of thousands of such trades and we don't want an error introduced in one trade to influence all consecutive trades PnLs.

Expected results:

Intermediate calculations
[image]

This is the final result I need:

[image]

Thank you!

Please sorry for my English.

Comment: It looks like you already have it. You just have the positives & negatives reversed on the RunningLocalAmount. Purchasing shares is a cash outflow and selling shares is a cash inflow.

Comment: Hi Jason, maybe I was not clear. I meant to have it calculated as a separate PnL. Starting from scratch each time. The one I have is a "continiuos" one.

Comment: Have you put some effort into this yourself? I assume what is needed is to make use of window functions like OVER together with LEAD or something. I am curious if/how this can be solved or if it needs to be solved in the client.

Comment: Hi @tk1977tk, could you add expected output please to make understandable. İn first instance I think you need to see row numbers 6 and 20 with  k_ExeShares and RunnincLocal values.

Comment: Joakim Danielson, I am not a very experinced SQL dev. I actually more real-time, embeded. This is as far as I could progress

Comment: Ayzek, for the first batch (1) the PnL would be -$444.44 in row 7.(or $444 as of Jason's comment above, because of different sign). For the second batch (2) PnL in row 21 should be $271.17 (or -$271.17 as of Jason's comment above, because of different sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be on the right track. You might try using `rollup` instead of using a `union` to get the details along with the summary rows. And of course if you don't need the detail rows then remove the union entirely.

```
with rnk as (
    select *,
        sum(case when Direction = 'OPENING' and RunningLocal = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
            over (order by Id) as Block,
        case when Direction = 'OPENING' then -1 else 1 end * K_ExeShares * ExePrice as Cashflow
    from T -- your table
)
select
    Block, Direction,
    99999 as id, null as K_ExeShares, null as ExePrice, null as Cashflow,
    sum(Cashflow) as Ttl,
    case when Direction = 'OPENING' then 'BOUGHT' else 'SOLD' end as "Description"
from rnk
group by Block, Direction
union all
select
    Block, Direction,
    Id, K_ExeShares, ExePrice, Cashflow,
    sum(Cashflow) over (partition by Block, Direction order by Id),
    Direction
from rnk
order by Block, Direction desc, Id;
```

I'm sure this can be improved. https://rextester.com/QFEKW74472

**Take #2**

Looks like this is closer:

```
with rnk as (
    select *,
        sum(case when Direction = 'CLOSING' and RunningTotal = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
            over (order by Id desc) as Block,
        -K_ExeShares * ExePrice as Cashflow
    from T -- your table
)
select
    max(Block) over () - Block as Block, Direction,
    Id, K_ExeShares, ExePrice, Cashflow,
    sum(Cashflow) over (partition by Block order by Id) as RunningTotalAmount
from rnk
order by Block, Direction desc, Id;
```

https://rextester.com/YMCX27766

Comment: Hi Shawn, running your code in Rexter seems like everyting is good. When I run your code on my datatable it produces strange results. Do you know how I can add my dataset here so you can see my actual data?

Comment: In SSMS you can script out tables. Another option is to use SQL Fiddle.

Comment: At SQLFiddle.com look for text to DDL on the menu. Change your db type first so it gets the right syntax.

Comment: Trying to build with sqlfiddler example but getting error: "Request content too large (>8000)" after pressing the Build Schema button... Here is a link to scripted Table with data [link](https://pastebin.com/hrWNg67m)

Comment: Just trim it down to the first couple example.

Comment: My approach was using the Id column. You could switch to using the date/time, I think. Also you yave a column called `RunningTotal` rather than `RunningLocal`. Seems to run for me with your data after making these changes.

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much.